# Meaning of "to be responsible for being..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The external safety unit is therefore responsible for the functions and applications being correct.

What is meant by the sentence above?

1. The external safety unit is therefore responsible for the correctness of functions and applications.
2. The external safety unit is therefore responsible for the functions and applications which are correct.

Comment: It's 1. And what would be the point of making some unit responsible for only the correct functions?

Answer (score 1):

It helps to simplify the sentence - **"*The unit is responsible for the items being correct"***.

What is the unit responsible for exactly? It is responsible for "the items being correct". So your first meaning is the correct one. If the items are currently correct, you wouldn't use "being" you would use "are" as you did in your second sentence.

The only way I can think of to use "being correct" with the meaning of your second sentence is *"The items, being correct, are good examples."* The continuous tense seems unnecessarily complicated to me though. I would typically write that sentence as "The items are correct, so they are good examples."